# The only maps $\mathbb A^1 \rightarrow C$ are constant if $C$ is a curve with genus $\geq 1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

My professor claimed that if $C$ is a curve over $k$ of genus $\geq 1$ the only morphisms $\mathbb A_k^1 \rightarrow C$ are the constant morphisms, or something along those lines I can't exactly remember. What is the relevant theorem here? Does $C$ also have to be smooth?

Comment: A non-constant rational map to a curve $\phi:\Bbb{A}^1_k\to C$ gives an embedding $k(C)\to k(t)$. There is a theorem that it means $k(C)=k(f)$ which has genus $0$, but I don't know an elementary argument. For complex curves it is easier. The algebraic approach may be to prove that $k(f(t),g(t))=k(h(t))$ where $h$ is any non-constant element with minimal number of poles in $\Bbb{P}^1$. Those things are birational invariants so we can always replace $\phi$ and $C$ by a morphism $\Phi:\Bbb{P}^1\to C'$ a smooth projective curve birational to $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nonconstant map $\Bbb A^1\to C$ gives an injection of function fields $k(C)\to k(t)$ with $t$ an indeterminant. By [Luroth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCroth%27s_theorem), such a subextension $k\subset k(C)\subset k(t)$ is of the form $k(f(t))$ for some rational function $f$. In particular, this cannot be the function field of a curve of positive genus: every such field is a nontrivial algebraic extension of $k(t)$. So our assumption that $\Bbb A^1\to C$ was nonconstant must have been incorrect.

(If you're looking for an elementary proof of Luroth's theorem, [Wikimedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Another_elementary_proof_of_Luroth%27s_theorem-06.2004.pdf) has an example.)

Comment: This is great! Thank you

Comment: The pdf is a mess, it should take 4 lines to state it in a clean way without introducing 40 letters.

Comment: @reuns I think the proof is acceptable, especially in the context of a response for someone who's newer at algebraic geometry or someone who might benefit from a proof which is more "hands-on". Do you have a different reference to suggest?